How to override List<T> like ToString() method in C#
I am trying to print a list on console like ToString() method, but how can I override while using list? For example:
public override string ToString()
{
    return "[" + string.Join(',', lable) + "]";
}

How can we override list method like above.
But what if I want to override this?
public override list<Node> list()
{
   
} 


Can you share a [mcve]?

" what if I want to override this" your example code doesn't make sense to me. Can you please clarify your requirement. What is this list method that you want to override?

If your base class has a virtual method called list() which returns list<Node>, you can override it exactly the way you showed it in your question.

You can't change the behaviour of the existing List<T> because C# / .NET do not have features to make that possible. The only way to do it is as shown in the Fiddle by Jon Skeet, with a custom subclass, and you'd have to use that subclass everywhere in your own code instead of List<T>.

If I understand what you want to do. You shouldn't. List, while it isn't a sealed class. (Thank you to @JonSkeet for clarifing this) You should not directly derive from it.
However if you really want to do that (god knows why because no code) you could put it in a custom Class as a property. Like this:
public class CustomList<T>
{
    private List<T> items = new List<T>();

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        items.Add(item);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "[" + string.Join(", ", items) + "]";
    }
}

However if you just want to override the Method because you want to control the print. Consider this:
    public static class ListExtensions {
        public static string ToCustomString<T>(this List<T> list)
        {
            return "[" + string.Join(", ", list) + "]";
        } 
}

This is a extensionemethod. It works in C# like a "Concat" of an existing Method (to oversimplify it strongly) you add a method to an existing Method without altering the base method. And in your case atleast in my opinion a lot cleaner... again only if you want to control the printoutput
Special Thanks to JonSkeet once again I post the fiddlesolution below which is also a good if not better way (he has way more experience than i do)
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new DerivedList<string> { "a", "b" };
        Console.WriteLine(list);
    }
}

public class DerivedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public override string ToString() => $"List with {Count} elements.";
}


"List is a sealed class" - no it isn't. (Note the lack of sealed in the docs.) It's generally a bad idea to derive from List<T>, but it is possible.

Interesting you are right. But you can't inherit from List to my knowledge. Doesn't that mean in theory it is sealed or if thats the case why should i NOT seal it?

"But you can't inherit from List to my knowledge." Did you try it? Here's a sample... https://dotnetfiddle.net/O9wVK7

Oh wow in this case i am kind of stupid. I will alter my Answer. I think I did try it a few years back when i started coding and ran into some issue. My supervisor back then advised me not to directly inherit but use the approach in my original answer. Maybe thats why I didn't look into detail or try it again. But you learn something new every day. Thanks alot

It is also recommend that your CustomList<T> implements IList<T> interface.

You are right @SomeBody I added the fiddle of Jon Skeet aswell since he utilizes this point aswell
